# ASP.NET webform system exception

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

There is a webform in a website written in ASP.NET and the request id field accepts only integer, but the user inputs a string, what happens user copied any thing of a string and pasted into this integer field, after click search then shows system exception.

How can rectify this issue?

Thank you

Comment: You can fix it by changing the code so that you no longer get an error. If you want a more detailed description of how to do that, you need to edit your question and provide more detail, including a [MCVE].

Comment: Validate your user input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to use `Exception Handling`.

You need to perform following set of steps:

`1) Validate user's input
2) Use Try Catch Block
3) Notify about the user about the error`